# Text domain for Woocommerce Custom text area

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I created a custom field in woocommerce in the general tab, as you can see here
[custom textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek2hk.png)

I need to create the text domain for the text I will insert in the textarea , to translate it with WPML string.

I tried inserting the text domain in the placeholder

> 'placeholder' => __('inserire tipo calzabilità', 'woocommerce')

but it doesn't work!
What's wrong?

below the code

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields');

function woocommerce_product_custom_fields()
{
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';

    //Custom Product  Textarea
    woocommerce_wp_textarea_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_custom_product_textarea',
            'placeholder' => 'inserire tipo calzabilità',
            'label' => __('Campo calzabilità', 'woocommerce')

        )
    );
    echo '</div>';

}

// Save Fields
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');


function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id)
{

// Custom Product Textarea Field
    $woocommerce_custom_procut_textarea = $_POST['_custom_product_textarea'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_procut_textarea))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_textarea', esc_html($woocommerce_custom_procut_textarea));

}

add_action( 'flatsome_custom_single_product_1', 'dancin_fit', 20 );

function dancin_fit() {

   echo '<div class="fit"><span>' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_custom_product_textarea', true) .'</span></div>';
}
```

Comment: As this code is going in your active child theme (or active theme), you need to use the text domain of your active theme. In WPML you will need to re-scan your active child theme (or active theme) files first and then you will be able to get them in string translation for the related domain.

Comment: Thank you for your help ... now the string is displayed ... but it shows me the text of the placeholder ... is there any way to display the text inserted by me in the textarea?